# Closing unhealthy connection after timeout. react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to react-native. I am getting following error when I am trying to connect with firebase from android device. It is working perfectly with emulator. I am using device for development.
Following is my code.

firebaseconfig.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

let HAS_INITIALIZED = false

const initFirebase = () => {
    if (!HAS_INITIALIZED) {
        const config = {
              apiKey: "***",
                authDomain: "****",
                databaseURL: "*****",
                storageBucket: "****",
                messagingSenderId: "****"
        }

        firebase.database.enableLogging(true)
        firebase.initializeApp(config)
        HAS_INITIALIZED = true
    }
}

export const getDatabase = () => {
    initFirebase()

    return firebase.database()

}
```

Action.js Code

```
getDatabase().ref('app')
 .once('value', async (snapshot) => {
  console.log('connected...');
  //it is not coming here
});
```

Error

p:0: Auth token refreshed
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 getToken() completed. Creating connection. 
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:0: Connection created
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://react-native-examples.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:0: Closing unhealthy connection after timeout.
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:0: Closing realtime connection.
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:0: Shutting down all connections
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:0:0 WebSocket is being closed
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 p:0: data client disconnected
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 p:0: Trying to reconnect in 494.7817354676815ms
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 0: onDisconnectEvents
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 p:0: Making a connection attempt
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 getToken() completed. Creating connection. 
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:1: Connection created
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:1:0 Websocket connecting to wss://react-native-examples.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:1: Closing unhealthy connection after timeout.
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:1: Closing realtime connection.
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:1: Shutting down all connections
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:1:0 WebSocket is being closed
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 p:0: data client disconnected
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 p:0: Trying to reconnect in 851.244468933819ms
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 0: onDisconnectEvents
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 p:0: Making a connection attempt
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 getToken() completed. Creating connection. 
D:\app\node_modules\firebase\database.js:50 c:0:2: Connection created

Comment: I am only getting this error on physical device with debuging mode. Without debuging mode it is also working perfectly.